# Windows Azure + SQL - Hobbyist website

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, cloud-hosting

I was wondering whether or not Windows Azure is a viable option, now that they offer 10 free websites, for hosting a simple website with a database and domain name etc.. or is more traditional web hosting still the better option?

The database won't be that big, so the $5 for the 100MB database option will be plenty. I guess a few dollar's would be needed for traffic too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a viable option. However, to get your own domain name you must change the website from free to shared or reserved mode. Heres description and link how to do this!

> "When you create a web site, Windows Azure provides a friendly
>   subdomain on the azurewebsites.net domain so your users can access
>   your web site using a URL like http://.azurewebsites.net.
>   However, if you configure your web sites for shared or reserved mode,
>   you can map your web site to your own domain name."

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns-web-site/

Comment: Ah, that adds an extra $9/month onto the bill. I think I'll stick to more traditional hosting as I can get all of this for $7 per month, whereas I'd be paying minimum $14 with Azure. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Custom domain names can only be used in Shared or Reserved modes which are not free.

The free websites would be under [yourSubdomain].azurewebsites.net

So, it depends whether having your own domain matters to you and, if so, whether you are willing to pay for the website.

Notwithstanding this, Azure websites is a perfectly good cloud solution offering quick deployment of numerous CMS systems including WordPress, Joomla, etc.